# arrange values and labels on plots yticks-xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, xticks

[image]

```
height_str=headers[1:]   #height format str
height=[float(i) for i in height_str]  #height format float -type:LIST

plt.yticks((height),height_str)  #height  y axis
```

Hello. I would like to display the values and labels in a better range on the plot. I use imshow for the graph.
height is a list that contains 156 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you supplied the ticks, you're telling matplotlib to place a tick at every height value you gave it. You need to give it only the specific ticks you want to use if you're doing things this way.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import face

# Generating my face heights
height = np.arange(0, 800)
height_str = list(map(str, height))
plt.imshow(face())
#plt.yticks(height,height_str)  # <- this is bad. Do this instead
plt.yticks(height[::50],height_str[::50]) # Gets every 50th entry
```

Otherwise, you could do this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(face())
ax.set_yticks(height[::50])
```

Edit: To format, you can use ticker functions.

```
from matplotlib import ticker
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:.2f}"))
```

From https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html

Comment: how can i round the values written in the axis? for example I get a value like  0.8048742

Comment: See my edit, I added a snippet on how to use the `StrMethodFormatter`.

Comment: Thank u soooo much!!  may I ask you if you could solve why the plot is cut at the top?  Ideas?

Comment: Probably because the height you provided is larger than the height of your image. In my example, the image has around 800 pixels of height. If you extend the `arange` to `1200`, you'll get a blank area similar to yours.

Comment: No. If you're certain of your values, try this: `plt.yticks(height[:n:50],height_str[:n:50])` and replace n with a value to cut your labels at the appropriate place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231069/discussion-between-steren-and-k-cl).